# switch from Netbook Edition 10.10 to Desktop Edition?

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-netbook, gnome-panel

I installed 10.10 netbook, and want to use the desktop edition. I tried logging in with the desktop edition profile running, but when it loads, there are no panels on top or bottom, so the experience is quite incomplete. How does one get those panels running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you install the `ubuntu-desktop` meta-package `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` this will ensure you have all the packages necessary for the base Gnome desktop to run. Once that package is installed you should be able to switch session like normal.

Comment: turns out that I had missing packages that prevented panels from displaying. Thanks!